# Запись на русском языке в файл .properties Java

Tags: java, файлы

Как записывать/считывать в файл .properties в Java
При использовании следующего кода записывает криво русские символы(вывод иероглифы):

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("Name", txtLogin.getText());
try {
  prop.store(
    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(newFileOutputStream("Config.properties"), "UTF-8")), null);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(LogIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(LogIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно отметил nwldx, в формате файла `.properties` предполагается кодирование всех символов кроме английских через `\uxxxx`. Но для того, чтобы корректно записать такой файл, использовать утилиту `native2ascii`, конечно же, не обязательно.

Достаточно записывать напрямую в файловый поток, минуя `OutputStreamWriter`, чтобы метод `store` самостоятельно закодировал все русские буквы как полагается.

Другие дело, если вы сознательно хотите нарушить формат файла, и хранить там все в UTF-8. В таком случае ваш код - *правильный*. Только что проверил на своем компьютере - он работает. Проблема либо в записываемой строке - либо при чтении файла.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте,

Единственный способ указать русские буквы - использовать формат `"\uxxxx"` и утилиту `native2ascii`.